# Simple C Program, Unknown output

Tags: c, arrays, int, long-integer

### Problem Statement

You are given an array of integers of size . You need to print the sum of the elements of the array.

Note: A signed 32-bit integer value uses  bit to represent the sign of the number and remaining 31 bits to represent the magnitude. The range of the 32-bit integer is . When we add several integer values, the resulting sum might exceed this range. You might need to use`long long int` in C/C++ or long data type in Java to store such sums.

### Input Format

The first line of the input consists of an integer. The next lines contain  space separated integers describing the array.

### Constraints

#### Output Format

Output a single value equal to the sum of the elements of the array.

### Sample Input

```
5
1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005`
```

### Sample Output

```
5000000015
```

### My program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    long int a[5],sum;
    for(i=0;i<=n-1;i++){
        scanf("%ld %ld %ld %ld %ld",&a[1],&a[2],&a[3],&a[4],&a[5]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<=n-1;i++){
        sum = sum + a[i];
    }
    printf("%ld",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

### Error description

Input (stdin):

```
5
1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005
```

Your Output (stdout):

```
140692151765426
```

Expected Output:

```
5000000015
```

Compiler Message:

```
Wrong Answer
```

Comment: You must initialize sum

Comment: And you cannot use `&a[5]` if `a` is just 5 elements long.

Comment: arrays are 0 indexed

Comment: Your code (once you fix the indexing) will only ever read 5 elements, regardless of the value of `n`.

Comment: it would be cleaner to use  a, a+1, a+2, a+3, a+4 instead of &a[1] etc. since a is a pointer anyway.

Comment: `long int a[5],sum=0;for(i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
        scanf("%ld", &a[i]);`

Comment: I disagree with your choice of accepted answer. [Shreevardhan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31593545/5420829) is the only answer under this question that works for n > 10. Variable length arrays and dynamically allocated arrays would work too, but nobody mentioned them.

Comment: P.S. Shreevardhan's solution is better than runtime-sized arrays because it's memory usage remains constant when n increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program has following issues:

1. Array indexing is wrong : Array is of size 5 starting from 0 , you can use only till a[4] , but for scanf() , it tries to read value as &a[5].
2. No use of for loop when you are using hard coded index a[1],a[2],etc. Instead the below code will be better to get input as follows:

---

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
  scanf("%ld",&a[i]);
}
```

---

3. Sum includes : sum = sum + a[i];

   when i = 0 --> a[0] will have have junk values because input was not taken from user as scanf started from a[1] . Since array is not initialized this is uninitialized auto variable, it might have junk values which will get added in the sum .
4. sum itself is also not initialized, so it will contain junk value and for very first addition : sum = sum + a[0]; thsi junk value will get added .

Hope this answer your query for unexpected output.

Answer (score 3):

This works fine :

```
#include <inttypes.h>
int main()
{
  int n,i;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  unsigned long long int a[5];
  unsigned long long int sum=0;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    scanf("%llu",&a[i]);
  }
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    printf("%llu\n",sum);
    sum = sum + a[i];
  }
  printf("\nSum is : %llu",sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Use the `ll` long-long modifier with the `u` (unsigned) conversion

Answer (score 2):

You don't basically need an array here. Just

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    long long int a, sum = 0;
    while (n--) {
        scanf("%lld", &a);
        sum += a;
    }
    printf("%lld", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To meet OP's "...resulting sum might exceed this range ...", suggest `long long sum = 0;`

Comment: @chux yes, but 140692151765426 > 5000000015

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  Yes, OP's `long` is certainly 48+ bits with output like `140692151765426`.  Yet a portable solution would use `long long` to meet the posted requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    int n,i;
    cin >> n;
    long long int s=0;
    long int a[10];
    if(n>=1 && n<=10)
        {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            cin>>a[i];
            s=s+a[i];
        }
    }
    cout<<s;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged `C`, not `C++`. Correct me if I'm wrong, but there is no `std`, `cin` and `cout` in `C`. Also you have a bunch of redundant (unused) `#include`s.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    long int a[10];
    long long sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<=n-1;i++){
        scanf("%ld",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<=n-1;i++){
        sum = sum + a[i];
    }
    printf("%ld",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, why does it solve the problem and what is the difference with OP's code. Thanks :)